Redirect a malformed incoming link?
A URL in a newsletter was copy and pasted incorrectly, so it returns the following error:
This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in https.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
Looking at the link in the newsletter it is encoded as https://https//www.example.com/....... We'll resend the newsletter with a corrected link, but, is there any way to redirect/rewrite that bad/malformed URL to the correct URL https://www.example.com/.....?

I doubt that is possible ... The issue is that "https//www.example.com" is not a valid host name in syntactic means, since it contains slashes that are not valid. So no DNS system will ever even attempt to resolve this address, even if a browser would send out a request for that, which I doubt. Without a DNS resolution no https request will ever get sent by any browser (where should it be sent to?), so there is no request you could redirect.

This might serve as a simple, though non authoritative reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

@arkascha Thanks. That's what I was afraid of.
